# AWS Data Pipeline; RedshiftLoadCopy failed; schema error

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I have created my schema in **Redshift** and want to use **Data pipeline** to populate my table with **csv** file in **S3**.

Under parameters for the field: `myRedshiftTableName`:

1. If I only use my **tableName** without specifying the **Schema**, then error is:

> output table named 'public.myTable' doesn't exist and no
>   createTableSql was provided

2. If I also specify the **Schema**, then the error is:

> output table named 'public.mySchema.myTable' doesn't exist and no
>   createTableSql was provided

3. If I drop the table and specify the **Schema** in `myRedshiftCreateTableSql` field, then the error is:

> ERROR: schema "mySchema" does not exist

How to use my own defined schema?

Comment: do you have to use aws data pipeline?

Comment: Yes, I do, I did it with COPY command, and it worked, but now I have to use data pipeline.

Comment: data pipeline - for what advantage? (i had a lot of trouble there!)

Comment: the goal is to make the process automated, like running a job on db after midnight, would you recommend any other way/services?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at DMS using S3 csv as the source http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html  DMS is a good tool

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit pipelines > data nodes > click on "Add an optional field" and then specify your schema name.